# python: IndexError: string index out of range

Tags: python

m learning python from the google tutorials. am stuck on an exercise related to lists.
getting an index error

```
  lis[j]=words.pop()[i]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

i need to sort the list but the words starting with x should be the first ones.

code is

```
def front_x(words):
    i=0
    lis=[]
    j=0
    k=0
    words.sort()

    while i<len(words):
        if words[i][0:1]=="x":
            lis[j]=words.pop()[i]
            j+=1
        i+=1
    lis.extend(words)
    while k<len(lis):
        print(lis[k])
        k+=1
    return
```

Comment: Can you post the data that you are using?

Answer (score 5):

`lis` is an empty list, *any* index will raise an exception.

If you wanted to add elements to that list, use `lis.append()` instead.

Note that you can loop over sequences *directly*, there is no need to keep your own counter:

```
def front_x(words):
    lis = []
    words.sort()

    for word in words:
        if word.startswith("x"):
            lis.append(word)
    for entry in lis:
        print(entry)
```

You can reduce this further by immediately printing all words that start with `x`, no need to build a separate list:

```
def front_x(words):
    for word in sorted(words):
        if word.startswith("x"):
            print(word)
```

If you wanted to sort the list with all `x` words coming first, use a custom sort key:

```
def front_x(words):
    return sorted(words, key=lambda w: (not w.startswith('x'), w))
```

sorts the words first by the boolean flag for `.startswith('x')`; `False` is sorted before `True` so we negate that test, then the words themselves.

Demo:

```
>>> words = ['foo', 'bar', 'xbaz', 'eggs', 'xspam', 'xham']
>>> sorted(words, key=lambda w: (not w.startswith('x'), w))
['xbaz', 'xham', 'xspam', 'bar', 'eggs', 'foo']
```

Comment: ur method wud work if words starting with x are already in alphabetical order. but if not, this would fail.
what exercise says is to arrange alphabetically the words with a condition that words starting with "x" shud be arranged first.

Comment: @shanzyshan: No, it will not. The key returns a tuple; after sorting on the first value the items are sorted on the second.

Comment: @martin. okk i'll try this.

Comment: as u might have figured out i am new to python. one thing i am unable to understand is that how in the for *** in *** statements, the compiler is able to pick up things when we have not already defined them.
for eg. in ur code this line is given
for word in words
we have just defined words as a list but how is compiler able to identify word.
even in for word in sorted(words)
neither is word defined and nor i think there is some command sorted().
can u explain me this?

Comment: @shanzyshan: The grammar for Python states that `word` will be assigned *to*. The compiler knows it is a assignment target, so `word` will be defined as a local name just by using it in the loop statement. This is all documented in the [Python reference documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/).

Answer (score 0):

> i need to sort the list but the words starting with x should be the first ones.

Complementary to the custom search key in @Martijn's extended answer, you could also try this, which is closer to your original approach and might be easier to understand:

```
def front_x(words):
    has_x, hasnt = [], []
    for word in sorted(words):
        if word.startswith('x'):
            has_x.append(word)
        else:
            hasnt.append(word)
    return has_x + hasnt
```

Concerning what was wrong with your original code, there are actually *three* problems with the line

```
lis[j]=words.pop()[i]
```

1. `lis[j]` only works if the list already has a `j`th element, but as you are adding items to an initially empty list, you should use `lis.append(...)` instead.
2. You want to remove the word starting with "x" at index `i` from the list, but `pop()` will always remove the *last* item. `pop()` is for stacks; never remove items from a list while looping it with an index!
3. You apply the `[i]` operator *after* you've popped the item from the list, i.e., you are accessing the `i`th *letter of the word*, which may be much shorter; thus the `IndexError`